# Google App Script: Creating a Unique RefNo, not writing incremented new refno correctly from protected sheet, cannot add leading zero to RefNo

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a support sheet for an NGO using GAS (Google App Scripting).

I have successfully been able to create a Unique Reference Number with the code below. and storing the incremented number that i use in the Reference Number on a hidden/protected sheet.

The issue is adding atleast 3 leading zero's

Example: Ticket 2 should have a reference T0002

But currently returning T2

Below is my code:

```
 function onSelect(event) {
 //This function creates a unique reference number
 //When a new support item is logged
 //It then stores the newest reference number on a locked sheet
 
  //Initialising Googlesheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange(); 
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Ticket");
  var wt = ss.getSheetByName("Ref");
  
  //Retrieves the row number that is being edited
  var rownum = r.getRow();
  //Initializing the first cell in the row to return its value 
  var data = ws.getRange(rownum,1).getValues();
  //Checks if the data in the cell is empty
  if(data == ""){
  //When the cell is empty it gets the latest Reference Number
  //Execute the GetLatest() Function
  var gl = GetLatest();
  // Increment the latest Reference Number by 1
  var newgl = gl + 1;
  //The new Reference number is now stored
  wt.getRange(1,1).setValue(newgl);
  // Creates the Reference Number that will be written in the Reference column on the Support Log
  // Execute NewRef() function
  var nr = NewRef();
  //Writes the new Reference number in the designated cell
  ws.getRange(rownum,1).setValue(nr);
  }
}
```

Created a function separately that fetches the latest reference number stored on the "Ref" sheet.

In cell A1 on the hidden sheet, I have stored value "0001".

```
function GetLatest(){
// This function fetches the latest reference number stored
  
 //Initialising Googlesheet and cell with the value
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Ref");
var row = 1;
var col = 1;
// fetches the value
var value = ws.getRange(row, col).getValue();
return value;
}
```

Inserts and creates a string for a unique reference number

```
function NewRef(){
 //This function creates the Reference number that the user sees on the Support Log
  
  //Initialising Googlesheet 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Ref");
  //Fetches latest Reference number
  var lr = GetLatest();
  //Creates support log reference number
  var cnr =  "T" + lr;
  return cnr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `lr` variable contains the latest reference, if I understand correctly. If you do `var cnr = addLeadingZeros(lr)` function below on it, you'll be fine. Please run the snippet below and confirm that it works as expected:

```js
const numbers = [7, 12, 34, 321, 4567, 89981];
const numLen = 4;

const addLeadingZeros = num =>
  '0'.repeat(numLen - (num + '').length >= 0 ? numLen - (num + '').length : 0) +
  (num + '');

numbers.forEach(num => console.log(`${num} becomes ${addLeadingZeros(num)}`));
```

Comment: HI Thanks for your contribution, the code didnt work when trying to implement it but what it did give me was the logic i need to apply. Will try and figure it out and post if i do get it to work

Comment: What exactly didn't work, if you click "Run code snippet" it does work, doesn't it?

Comment: im fairly new to this so apologies, if i dont make sense, the snippet worked when i ran it. tried to implement it to my code then it didnt.

Comment: Can you share how you exactly you implemented it?